# (Automatically) convert SQL strings to 'enums'?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

We have a PostgreSQL database with billions of entries in the form:

```
CREATE TABLE entry (
  session integer NOT NULL,
  time integer NOT NULL,
  key text NOT NULL,
  data text NOT NULL
)
```

In this database `key` is a developer-defined string, while `data` is user-defined content. In other words, while there are virtually infinitely many `data` entries, there is only a very limited amount of `key` entries.

Is there a way to tell SQL to optimize on `key` in such a way of telling it:

> *Well, you might receive a string, but you really should convert it to and store it as an integer since you will only receive a very finite amount of these (say, 300)*.

Of course we *could* create a 2nd table and translate / hash incoming strings and do explicit (reverse) lookups when performing queries. However, my feeling was that there must / should be a way to automate this.

We are currently using PostgreSQL 9.3, but we're willing to upgrade to later versions (and potentially even to other (No)SQL solutions) that can handle the above data time- and space-efficiently.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I forgot to clarify, the reason we cannot use Enums is that because the `key` values are defined implicitly by a bunch of distributed developers that do not have database access. Which means, although there are only finitely many keys, they are created from the databases perspective on-the-fly.

**Edit 2:** More mathematically speaking, an implicitly applied, collision-free but small (in terms of target width) hash function might would do the trick if it existed.

**Edit 3:** And the reason why using a 2nd table is unfeasible is because we have a bunch of very complex queries which refer to `key` numerous times. If we had to redirect to a 2nd table every time things would probably get even messier and harder to understand.

Comment: I'm a little confused, you mention enums in your title. Your problem appears to be what enums were designed for. But you don't say why using enums isn't apropriate.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html

Comment: Sorry, updated my post for clarity. The keys are not known a-priori.

Comment: Ad edit3: could be automated with triggers (or updatable views). *Allowing* INSERTs with any value by anyone does not combine nicely with your goal of *restricting* them via enums (or a foreign key to a "domain table")

Comment: Do the keys have any kind of pattern to them? Is there an upper bound on the length?

Comment: Examples could be `productX.moduleY.functionZ` or `some.interesting.event`. Thinking about it, the only thing they have in common is that they are ascii string separated by dots.

Comment: From what you've mentioned @left4bread I'd second the Updatable Views.  Never underestimate the usefulness of a human readable `SELECT * FROM ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in facility to do what you want, at least in PostgreSQL. Doing it effectively would require signifciant changes to how data is stored, as currently each row is independent of all other rows (well, except TOAST pointers for out-of-line stored data that's unchanged in an UPDATE). A column store could do kind-of what you want by highly compressing the keys but would introduce other problems for some query patterns.

Your best bet is very likely to be the side lookup table. To solve the issues with query complexity (additional joins, planning time, etc) I would probably write a lookup function, so all references to `key` could be replaced with `lookup_key(key)`.

A naïve implementation of `lookup_key` would just be a SQL function that does a `SELECT`. Such a function can even be inlined and optimized away if defined `STABLE` but not `STRICT`, so this might be a surprisingly good option.

A more sophisticated alternative if the key lookup table is effectively static would be to write a function that builds a session-lifetime in-memory cache as an associative array (hash) of the table when first called. You'd want to write it either in a procedural language like PL/Python, or in C. Subsequent calls could just look up the associative array, completely removing the need to access the other table. This might offer a big performance gain if done in C, but I suspect the costs of doing it in PL/Python or PL/Perl would actually outweigh the benefits of avoiding a simple scan of a cached table. The function would have to fall back to an SPI SQL query if it couldn't find the row, since it might've been added since the cache was built.

Comment: If I could I'd +1 for the lookup_key() function, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 options:

1. PostgreSQL supports [enumeration types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html) if your set of keys is predefined.
2. You can create an external table with an explicit mapping from any integer type (as primary key) and the corresponding key string and then only store the foreign key to this table in the main table.

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize `key` into a domain-table, and add a FK to that. Below, I add a numerical FK pointing to a domain-tabel, but you could just as wel use the `key` text field to refer to the table of allowable strings. (it would make your table a bit fatter, but it would also make the updates/inserts a bit simpler) Another way would be to wrap an updateble view around the two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE entry (
  session integer NOT NULL
  , time integer NOT NULL
  , key text NOT NULL
  , data text NOT NULL
  );

CREATE TABLE key_domain
        ( key_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , key_text text NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO key_domain (key_text)
SELECT DISTINCT key FROM entry;

ALTER TABLE entry
        ADD COLUMN key_id INTEGER
        ;
UPDATE entry e
SET key_id = k.key_id
FROM key_domain k
WHERE e.key = k.key_text
        ;

ALTER TABLE entry
        ADD CONSTRAINT key_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (key_id) REFERENCES key_domain(key_id)
        ;
ALTER TABLE entry
        ALTER COLUMN key_id SET NOT NULL
        ;
ALTER TABLE entry
        DROP COLUMN key
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to create a hash code on the front side (in the applications) and to use that one in the DB?

```
int hash = key.GetHashCode();
```

In the DB you would have a lookup table with string key / hash key pairs. But it would only be used for lookups, in case you want to know the string belonging to a hash code, not for queries.

If you want to query the entry table by key, then get the hash code in the application and use it directly in the query **without** joining the entry table to the lookup table.

Comment: Hashing would theoretically work. However, my main concerns are the probability of collisions vs. storage inefficiency (e.g., 1 byte storage == guaranteed collisions, 8 bytes of storage == no collisions but very inefficient); and it will be impossible to "discover" existing keys.

Comment: A 32-bit integer has a range of 4 billion numbers. It is very unlikely that you get a collision from only 300 enums. Why do you want to save 3 bytes by using a byte? We have terabyte hard disks today! The lookup table I mentioned would store each unique key as string and as hash-code in the DB. When introducing a new key, you would have to add an entry to this table, enabling you to discover existing keys. Note: the hash code in this table is only for convenience, as you can always re-calculate the hash code from the string key.

Comment: As I said, I am not ruling it out and 8 byte hashes would work (for 4 bytes I find the collision probability too high if we suddenly got more keys). It's just that I think it's not elegant and we lose the ability to list all keys.

Comment: You would not lose the ability to list all keys, if you add each unique key to a lookup table (in the DB).